# Angular - 'this' keyword doesn't have component instance

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

'this' is not working as expected

I am working with Angular 13.2.0 and Kendo UI for Angular 2+

I have multi select dropdown in my page and I want to disable few items based on condition so as per kendo documentation I have implemented

```
`<kendo-multiselect [data]="itemList" textField="id" valueField="id" [valuePrimitive]="true"                             
        [maxlength]="dataItem.maxAllowedItems"
        [itemDisabled]="itemDisabled">                              
 </kendo-multiselect>`
```

And in ts file

```
itemDisabled(itemArgs: { dataItem: DropdownItem, index: number }) { 
     return this.checkItemDisabled(itemArgs.dataItem);
}
checkItemDisabled(dataItem:DropdownItem){
     // condition code
     // return true or false based on condition
}
```

but when I am debugging in browser its giving  error like

> ERROR TypeError: this.checkItemDisabled is not a function

Even when I am trying to access other members of component using this its showing undefined because for this event 'this' is representing dropdown instance not component.

[image: When I mouse hover on 'this' while debugging its showing]

How can I get component reference inside this event?

I can not pass other parameters also to this event handler.

Comment: Looks like a simple typo: `checkItemDisaled` should be `checkItemDisabled`

Comment: Sorry, it was mistake while posting question. Corrected now!
And there is no compilation error in my code

Comment: The code you show looks fine. But i need to see more. But before you post more details try this: `itemDisabled = (itemArgs: { dataItem: DropdownItem, index: number }) => { 
     return this.checkItemDisabled(itemArgs.dataItem);
}` A anonymous function handle the this keyword different.

Comment: Thanks @Flo its working. 
Otherwise for work around I have created method and properties as static and access through component itself.